# Prometheus Presto-Exporter Configuration on Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, presto

I am trying to monitor Presto metrics using prometheus presto-exporter (https://github.com/yahoojapan/presto_exporter).
I have download the presto-exporter docker image and created the deployment and service. But, I am not quite sure, if I am doing it correctly. I am providing the deployment and service configuration below.

**deployment config**

```yaml
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: presto-exporter

    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: presto-exporter
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: presto-exporter
        spec:
          containers:
          - env:
            - name: web_url
              # (login credentials are required to access presto which is (username:=<domain\username>, password=<password with special characters>))
              value: "https://<vm_url>:<nodeport>/v1/cluster"
            - name: log_level
              value: "debug"
            - name: insecure_skip_verify
              value: "true"
            image: <registry-ip>/presto-exporter:latest
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            name: presto-exporter
            ports:
            - containerPort: 9483
              protocol: TCP
          imagePullSecrets:
          - name: <registry-secret>
```

**service config**

```yaml
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: presto-exporter
      name: presto-exporter
    spec:
      ports:
      - name: metrics
        port: 8280
        protocol: TCP
        targetPort: 9483
      selector:
        app: presto-exporter
      type: ClusterIP
```

I am doubtful if the usage of the environment variables are correct. Also, the exporter doesnt have any variable for username and password, and I am having trouble using the credentials for presto with only the --web.url flag.

Logs for the running pods gives me

```yaml
    kubectl logs presto-exporter-6dfd7db784-pqv7v
    time="2020-08-05T07:42:50Z" level=info msg="Starting presto_exporter (version=0.1.0, branch=master, revision=6eb4094fcd17f7fb82a393b527e3b0536ff1b38c)" source="presto_exporter.go:121"
    time="2020-08-05T07:42:50Z" level=info msg="Build context (go=go1.12.1, user=root@9756c8050182, date=20190323-04:33:01)" source="presto_exporter.go:122"
    time="2020-08-05T07:42:50Z" level=info msg="Listening on :9483" source="presto_exporter.go:137"
    time="2020-08-05T07:42:56Z" level=error msg="Get http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" source="presto_exporter.go:145"
    time="2020-08-05T07:43:01Z" level=error msg="Get http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" source="presto_exporter.go:145"
    time="2020-08-05T07:43:01Z" level=error msg="Get http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" source="presto_exporter.go:145"
    time="2020-08-05T07:43:06Z" level=error msg="Get http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" source="presto_exporter.go:145"
    time="2020-08-05T07:43:06Z" level=error msg="Get http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8080: connect: connection refused" source="presto_exporter.go:145"
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. And please let me know if you need more info.
Thanks in advance...

**EDIT**

I tried with different options in the sidecar container, and I have copied all the thing I have tried so far. I have added the configmap which has the certificates and credentials in it using envFrom and also tried using volumeMounts as it is mentioned in the main container.

```yaml
- name: presto-exporter
          args:
          - "--web.url=https://<vm_ip>:8901"
          - "--log.level=debug"
          image: <registry_ip>/presto-exporter:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          envFrom:
          - configMapRef:
              name: presto-master-config
          ports:
            - containerPort: 9483
              protocol: TCP
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /usr/lib/presto/configmap
              name: presto-master-config
            - mountPath: /usr/lib/presto/plugin/
              name: presto-plugin
            - mountPath: /usr/lib/presto/default/etc/catalog
              name: presto-catalog
            - mountPath: /certs
              name: <cert_name>
```

If I comment out the `--web.url` arg, I am getting the same error as before "connection refused", same goes for using "localhost:8901". Only way I can access the url if I use the vm IP and port of the main container.

Now if I curl "`http://<vm_ip>:9483/metrics`" and see the log, I am getting certification issue.

```
level=error msg="Get https://<vm_ip>:8901: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
```

and if I try with http in the `--web-url` arg then I am getting

```
level=error msg="Get http://<vm_ip>:8901: net/http: HTTP/1.x transport connection broken: malformed HTTP response
```

so, I guess I have to use https and find a way to solve the certification issues...

Answer (score 0):

This Prometheus exporter can scrape the metrics from the presto cluster, and it **should be installed in the coordinator server** of the presto cluster.

That means the exporter image should be in the sidecar container of the coordinator pods in the presto cluster. Then it will be able to scrape metrics from `http://localhost:8080/v1/cluster` URL.

If you really want it to be in the separate pod, you need to provide flag [-web.url](https://github.com/yahoojapan/presto_exporter/blob/master/presto_exporter.go#L114) instead of env `web_url`.

```yaml
      containers:
      - args:
        - "-web.url=http://<vm_url>:<nodeport>/v1/cluster"
        image: <registry-ip>/presto-exporter:latest
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: presto-exporter
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9483
          protocol: TCP
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. using args lets me access the correct url. Now, i am facing two more issues. first, I need https and login credentials and another error i am getting is "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority".
i dont see any flags for ignoring the certificates. 
sorry, i am a bit new on this. could you tell me how to avoid these?

Comment: @N.Farhan I'm afraid that you cannot do it by using the current version of the exporter. It doesn't provide an option for certificate authority (CA). It doesn't support the auth method either. You will need an `HTTP` server with the auth method disabled to use it.

Comment: @N.Farhan providing credentials like `username` & `password` via `args` (ie. URL ) isn't a good practice, try to avoid it.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I havent worked on that for a while.
I played around with sidecar container for a while and I am getting some new problems.
I have updated the question above. Any suggestions on how do I fix that? Thanks